# ¿Cómo almacenar correctamente un documento en Oracle, usando JSF?

Tags: java, oracle, base64

Estoy creando una aplicación en [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) y necesito subir un documento para almacenarlo posteriormente en una base de datos [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle).
Uso [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) para subir el archivo.

Hice las pruebas correspondientes y el archivo se sube y descarga, pero al descargarlo, el archivo descargado, está **corrupto** y el **peso de éste es superior al archivo original**.

Desconozco el motivo por el cual esto se puede producir, quizás estoy haciendo alguna conversión mal, que creo es lo más probable, pero en realidad no sé como validar eso.

El código para subir el documento en cuestión es el siguiente.

xhtml

```
<p:fileUpload label="Buscar" update="@form" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{sdocumento.handleFileUpload}"></p:fileUpload>
```

ManagedBean

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    //llenado de los datos para el modelo de documento en la bd
    documento.setcSiniestro(cSiniestro);
    documento.setcDocumento(selectedDocument);
    documento.setEliminado("N");
    documento.setTipoSiniestro(msiniestro.getcSiniestro());
    documento.setNombreArchivo(event.getFile().getFileName());
    documento.setTipoArchivo(obtenerExtencionArchivo(event.getFile().getFileName().toString()));
    documento.setContentType(event.getFile().getContentType());
    //esta es la parte en que se extrae el inputStream
    InputStream in= event.getFile().getInputstream();
    //transformación de inputStream a Base64 mediante función expuesta más abajo
    documento.setArchivo64(inputStreamToBase64(in));

    if(cd.insertDocumento(documento)){//insertar en la base de datos
        m.show("info", "Documento guardado correctamente");
    }else{
        m.show("error", "Error al guardar el documento");
    }
    setDocumento(new DocumentoVO());//se vuelve a inicializar el documento para posterior uso
    setDocumentos(cd.getDocumentos(cSiniestro));//se actualiza lista de documentos que ya fueron subidos
}

private String inputStreamToBase64(InputStream in) throws IOException{

    String base64="";
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int chunkSize = 10000000;
    byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(chunk)) > 0) {
        byte[] ba = new byte[bytesRead];

        for(int i=0; i<ba.length;i++){
            ba[i] = chunk[i];
        }
        base64 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, true);
    }
    in.close();
    return base64;
}
```

El documento es subido a la base de datos siendo guardado en [base64](/questions/tagged/base64), haciendo uso del manejo de archivos con `oracle clob`. Una de las maneras para subir el archivo en `base64` es insertar primero el registro, luego dejarlo tomado con un `SELECT FOR UPDATE` y posteriormente efectuar un `update` al registro subiendo el `clob`.

Función para subir el documento.

```
public boolean insertDocumento(DocumentoVO documento){

    boolean flag = false;//flag para saber si el procedimiento se efectuó correctamente
    int correlativo = getNextVal();//obtenido de una sequencia
    //creación del registro
    String insert ="INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOS.DOCUMENTOSINIESTRO(CORRELATIVO,CODIGOSINIESTRO,TIPODOCUMENTO, TIPOSINIESTRO, NOMBREARCHIVO,TIPOARCHIVO,CONTENTTYPE,ELIMINADO,FECHASUBIDA,ARCHIVO64)VALUES("
            + correlativo
            + ","+documento.getcSiniestro()
            + ","+documento.getcDocumento()
            + ","+documento.getTipoSiniestro()
            + ",'"+documento.getNombreArchivo()
            + "','"+documento.getTipoArchivo()
            + "','"+documento.getContentType()
            + "','"+documento.getEliminado()
            + "',SYSDATE,empty_clob())";
    //select para dejar tomado el registro
    String select = "SELECT ARCHIVO64 FROM DOCUMENTOS.DOCUMENTOSINIESTRO WHERE CORRELATIVO ="+correlativo+" FOR UPDATE";
    //update para subir el documento en base64
    String update = "UPDATE DOCUMENTOS.DOCUMENTOSINIESTRO SET ARCHIVO64 = ? WHERE CORRELATIVO = "+correlativo;
    try{
         cOra = new ConexionOraclePool();//crea nueva conexión
         cOra.getConexion().setAutoCommit(false);//se deshabilita el autocommit para poder usar el FOR UPDATE
         pst = cOra.getConexion().prepareStatement(insert);
         if(pst.executeUpdate()>0){//si inserta
             pst = cOra.getConexion().prepareStatement(select);
             rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){//si se efectuó el select correctamente
                oracle.sql.CLOB clob = (oracle.sql.CLOB) rs.getClob("ARCHIVO64");
                clob.putString(1, documento.getArchivo64());
                pst = cOra.getConexion().prepareStatement(update);
                pst.setClob(1, clob);
                if(pst.executeUpdate()>0){//si updatea
                    flag =true;
                }
            }
         }
         cOra.getConexion().commit();
         rs.close();
         pst.close();
     }catch (Exception ex) {
         flag = false;//si ocurre algún error 
         System.out.println(insert);
         System.out.println(select);
         System.out.println(update);
        Logger.getLogger(DocumentoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            cOra.cierraConexion();//cierre de conexión
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DocumentoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Hasta esta parte en la base de datos, al revisar que hay en `ARCHIVO64` se pueden apreciar una serie de caracteres que deberían ser los correspondientes al documento en base64, digo "deberían" porque no tengo como comprobarlo hasta el momento.

Para poder descargar el documento el código es el siguiente.

xhtml

```
<h:dataTable value="#{sdocumento.documentos}" var="doc" styleClass="table table-condensed table-hover">
...
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Archivo" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:commandLink  ajax="false" value="#{doc.nombreArchivo}" >
        <p:fileDownload  value="#{sdocumento.downloadFile(doc)}"></p:fileDownload>
    </p:commandLink>
</h:column>
...
```

ManagedBean

```
public StreamedContent downloadFile(DocumentoVO doc){

    //input stream formado por el archivo rescatado de la base de datos mediante una función a explicar abajo
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cd.getDataDocumento(doc.getCorrelativo()));
    //streamedContent para formar el archivo a descargar
    StreamedContent fileDown=new DefaultStreamedContent(input,doc.getContentType(),doc.getNombreArchivo());
    return fileDown;
}
```

Función para obtener el documento desde la base de datos.

```
public byte[] getDataDocumento(int correlativo){

    byte[] data = "Any String you want".getBytes();//para inicializar.
    //select del archivo en base64
    String sql ="SELECT ARCHIVO64 FROM DOCUMENTOS.DOCUMENTOSINIESTRO WHERE CORRELATIVO ="+correlativo;
    try{
         cOra = new ConexionOraclePool();
         pst = cOra.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
         rs = pst.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()){
             oracle.sql.CLOB clob = (oracle.sql.CLOB)rs.getClob(1);
             //se guardan el archivo en byte[]
             data = IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getCharacterStream(), "UTF-8");
         }
         rs.close();
         pst.close();
     }catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(sql);
        Logger.getLogger(DocumentoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            cOra.cierraConexion();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DocumentoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El archivo que recuperas de base de datos está en base 64. Sin embargo en esta línea lo tratas como si fuera UTF-8 en vez de base 64:

```
data = IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getCharacterStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Tienes que hacer la conversión inversa que hiciste con la función `inputStreamToBase64` en vez de tratarlo como UTF-8.

Comment: Exactamente ese era el problema, he creado una función inversa que transforma de `base64` a `InputStream` y he hecho algunos cambios en la obtención del clob para retornar un `String` con el contenido en base64.